# Laravel Collection of Multiple relation items

Tags: php, laravel

I have a **User** that has many **Shops**, And a Shop has many **Products**

> Now I'm wondering, Is there a way that I can get a Collection of all products for this User.

Without having to loop through the shops he has.

#### Current method, Which returns a Collection of Shops with Products instead of a Collection of Products

```
$products = \Auth::user()->shops()->with('products')->get();
```

Answer (score 5):

You'll want to define a [HasManyThrough relation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)

```
class User extends Model
{
    ...
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Product', 'App\Shop');
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'skus.shop_id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `skus`.*, `shops`.`user_id` from `skus` inner join `shops` on `shops`.`id` = `skus`.`shop_id` where `shops`.`user_id` = 2), oh and  (SKU = PRODUCT)

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the products from multiple shops by using the [pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-pluck) method.

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->shops->pluck('products');
}

public function shops()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Shop::class);
}
```

(`$this` being an instance of your user model)

And on your shops model you must have a Laravel relationship to products

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
}
```

Comment: It's working if I name it "getProductsAttribute", otherwise it's telling a relation method must return a relation.

Comment: Your user model must have a relation to shops and your shop model must have a relation to products.